# Set up RefineryCMS with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm trying to get a RefineryCMS install running on my CentOS VPS (which has DirectAdmin installed, which I don't think makes any difference for my problem) but somehow I cannot get it to host.

In my httpd.conf I've added the following:

```
RailsEnv development
PassengerHighPerformance on
|?DOCROOT=/home/user/domains/domain.name/public_html/rails/refinery_test_install/|
```

The paths are all correct and my normal Rails 3 applications work perfectly when I put these lines in my httpd.conf yet now it will just load the index.html file I've put in the directory pure for testing.

Any ideas on how I could get this up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was totally missing I didn't forwarded passenger to Rails' public folder. The configuration works with the following docroot:

```
|?DOCROOT=/home/user/domains/domain.name/public_html/rails/refinery_test_install/public/|
```